# Naming ID in Android Applications

Tags: java, android

If you are developing Android application, you will encounter such a id naming in xml files of view and layouts :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/quit"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_quit"
          android:title="@string/quit" />
</menu>
```

and I am really wondering why such naming is applied to ids. It is because of Linux? What kinda meaning this naming --`@+id/...`--has?

When I am looking at `android:icon` attribute I can interpret that it means `ic_new_game` is located under drawable folder and `@` means "located at" or I just assume that.

But naming id attributes are kinda different because they also have `+` sign. Can somebody help me understand this convention?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a naming convention defined by the Android developers I guess. The `+` is only used when you want to define a new Id for something. Otherwise you just reference is like `@id/...`.

The `@drawable/...` and `@string/...` just represent a reference to some resources. Where drawable references get created automatically for `.png`, `.jpg`, `.gif` and `.xml` files residing in one of your `drawable` directories. The filename of your file will be the identifier.

The string references get created if there is a XML file containing string tags like this one `<string name="some_name">Some Name</string>`. The identifier for strings will be what you define as the name argument. In this example it would be `@string/some_name`.

Same applies for your layouts. You will be able to access them through `@layout/...`.

As far as I know it has nothing to do with Linux or at least I don't know anything in Linux like that.

An interesting read about this is [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) on the developer site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't see article before. Looks great.